# create a custom view helper not working in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to create a custom view helper in zf2 for testing

I created it as below...
inside Application\View\Helper\LiveStreaming.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;


class LiveStreaming extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($name = 'Unnamed')
    {
         return "$name , this is Zend Framework 2 View Helper";
    }
}
?>
```

inside Application\Module.php

```
<?php
public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(

                'liveStreaming' => function($name) {
                    return new View\Helper\LiveStreaming($name);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
?>
```

Now I am calling that view inside different model call News

News\view\news\news\index.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->liveStreaming('Ivan Gospodinow'); ?>
```

its not giving any response. Can you please tell me where I am doing mistake. I have checked almost all stackoverflow example, but not getting my answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Its not giving any response" is unlikely. If you're getting a blank page, you probably have display errors disabled, so check your error logs to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a factory here. Just replace

```
       'factories' => array(

            'liveStreaming' => function($name) {
                return new View\Helper\LiveStreaming($name);
            },
        ),
```

with

```
    'invokables' => array('liveStreaming' => 'Application\View\Helper\LiveStreaming')
```

in your `Module.php`

Comment: Hi Ronnie Thanks a lot for the answer. But still the same error. Now My Module.php like `public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array('liveStreaming' => 'Application\View\Helper\LiveStreaming')
        );
    }` it always gives "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Well I simulated your case and nothing went wrong. So try enabling your errors.

Comment: Hi Ronnie, its telling `Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\LiveStreaming' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170` though its is there inside `Application\Application\View\Helper\LiveStreaming.php;` . Please help me. How to remove this error

Comment: the way you configured your namespace it got to be inside Application/src/View/Helper